# Присвоить массиву символов строку в тернарном операторе

Tags: c

Только начал учить С.
Мне нужно проверить условие и записать в память строку "YES" либо "NO" в зависимости от истинности условия. Так же мне нельзя использовать условные конструкции.
Пытаюсь вот так:

```
char s[4];
s = (a + b + c == d + e + f) ? "YES" : "NO";
```

Но выдает ошибку к этой строке: "Ошибка (активно)   E0137   выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением".

Comment: `#include <string.h> ... const char* src[2] = {"NO", "YES"}; strcpy(s, src[a+b+c == d+e+f]);`

Comment: В инициализации массива нельзя использовать тернарный оператор, но в инициализации указателя — [можно](https://godbolt.org/z/3xG4TYco8).

Comment: Массиву нельзя присвоить строку. Её можно скопировать в массив `(a + b + c == d + e + f) ? strcpy(s,"YES") : strcpy(s, "NO")`. Но вариант wololo гораздо более красив. И к тому же тернарный оператор это тоже условная конструкция. Или вам только `if()` нельзя использовать?

Comment: Или даже так (одним выражением) `strcpy(s, (a + b + c == d + e + f) ? "YES" : "NO");`

Comment: Также можно использовать `sprintf(s, "%s", (a + b + c == d + e + f) ? "YES" : "NO");` (в данном случае это избыточно, но если надо сформировать не столь тривиальный строковый ответ, то ... . / Во многих практических случаях весьма полезным может оказаться аналог sprintf -- [asprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу свои пять копеек, а именно "составные литералы" появившиеся в С99

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *s;
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
    int d = 3, e = 0, f = 0;

    s = (const char *[]){"NO", "YES"}[a+b+c == d+e+f];
    printf("%s\n", s);

    char s1[4];
    e = 1;
    strcpy(s1, (const char *[]){"No", "Yes"}[a+b+c == d+e+f]);
    printf("%s\n", s1);

    printf("%s\n", (const char *[]){"Nooo", "Yeeah"}[a+b+c == d+e+f]);
    return 0;
}
```